# Double-Mouse-1 doesn't do selection

Tags: mouse, config

When I do a double click, I don't see any selection.
Is there anything I need to enable to make it work?
Other mouse functionalities work fine.
See http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Word-and-Line-Mouse.html

Here is my mouse configuration

```
;; Enable mouse support
  (require 'mouse)
  (xterm-mouse-mode t)
  (global-set-key [mouse-4] (lambda ()
                              (interactive)
                              (scroll-down 1)))
  (global-set-key [mouse-5] (lambda ()
                              (interactive)
                              (scroll-up 1)))
  (defun track-mouse (e))
```

EDIT:
I use emacs through a terminal: I ssh from ubuntu terminal to a remote machine and run emacs -nw on the remote machine.

Comment: Are you using the terminal or a GUI version of Emacs?

Comment: I use the terminal version.

Comment: I remember fixing this recently-ish.  My guess is that it should be fixed in 24.5.